# SQL Stored Procedure and ASP.NET API Controller

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, http-delete

I am trying to write a stored procedure for my delete method. It works with the string query I created but I'm trying to make it more safe. This is what I had before my changes.

**Before Stored Procedure**
*Controller*

```
[HttpDelete]
        public JsonResult Delete(int ID)
        {
            string query = @"DELETE FROM dbo.WeatherForecast WHERE ID =" + ID;

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("WeatherAppCon");
            SqlDataReader myReader;
            using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
            {
                myCon.Open();
                using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myCon))
                {
                    
                   
                    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    table.Load(myReader);

                    myReader.Close();
                    myCon.Close();
                }
            }


            return new JsonResult("Row Deleted Successfully");
        }
```

**After Stored Procedure**
*Controller*

```
    [HttpDelete]
    public JsonResult Delete(int ID)
    {
        string query = "dbo.p_WeatherForecastDelete";

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("WeatherAppCon");
        SqlDataReader myReader;
        using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
        {
            myCon.Open();
            using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myCon))
            {
                
               
                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                table.Load(myReader);

                myReader.Close();
                myCon.Close();
            }
        }


        return new JsonResult("Row Deleted Successfully");
    }
```

*SQL Stored Procedure (Doesn't work)*

```
USE [WeatherTemplate]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_WeatherForecastDelete]
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM dbo.WeatherForecast WHERE ID = + ID;
END
```

Comment: Why are you using a stored procedure just to delete a single record? What advantage are you hoping to get by doing so?

Comment: This is merely for learning purposes.

Comment: What are you learning? You should note that your first code example is vulnerable to SQL Injection attack because you didn't properly parameterize your query. String concatenation is to be avoided when invoking SQL. You should learn about [Little Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/). For your stored procedure, you have not declared a variable to pass in an ID. Learn about [parameters in T-SQL procs](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/162/sql-server-stored-procedure-with-parameters/).

Comment: Yes, that is why I'm wanting to use a stored procedure instead. I'm just not sure how to correctly do that. I showed the first example to show what I was doing beforehand.

Comment: You're wanting to use a stored procedure for security? That's pointless. You can be just as secure with a properly parameterized query. Look at the link for Little Bobby Tables I sent you. Click C# on the left, then the ADO.NET page. You'll see plenty of info there about how to properly parameterize it. A stored procedure for this is a complete waste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things to correct:

1. Specify SqlCommand type

   myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
2. Add parameters

   myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", ID));
3. Fix stored procedure to receive parameter and use it properly

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_WeatherForecastDelete]
        @ID INT
    AS
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM dbo.WeatherForecast WHERE ID = @ID;
    END
```

*You also don't seem to be reading execution results so you can safely replace myCommand.ExecuteReader() with myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()*

Comment: Thank you, I have it working now. However, I am using this method to delete list entries from the table on my front end in Angular. How might I access the ID # from the database on the front end so my table knows which entry to delete? For example how do I pass the query string "WeatherForecast/?ID=*chosen number based on delete button for each entry in the list*

Comment: @Lwood That would be a separate question, though you should of course research it properly before asking it.

Comment: @Lwood - can you please up the answer if that's a correct one?
As for passing the parameter from Angular - that would be Angular topic. You'd need to provide more details on how you're pulling and displaying the data on Angular front-end but in the nutshell you just need to make Delete request to the controller above from Angular service.